# Vaadin 14 Embedded Jetty 9.4 + Spring boot do not persist session

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a project with Vaadin 14 + Spring Boot 2.4.5 which runs on the embedded Jetty / jetty-maven-plugin 9.4

In my current Setup, sessions get persisted. I did not configure this (knowingly) and I don't want it.

I found how to *enable* session persistence:
https://docs.huihoo.com/jetty/the-definitive-reference/using-persistent-sessions.html#enabling-persistence-for-jetty-maven-plugin

The default value should be no persistence but I find no hint how to get back to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedded Jetty is managed by Spring Boot. You can set `server.servlet.session.persistent=false` in `application.properties` to disable session persistence.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. i actually tried to set this before, but I set it on "false". It's a little un-intuitive o.0

Comment: That's actually a typo. It's supposed to be `false` that you should set, I'll make an edit for that. The point is however that the setting is managed through `application.properties` when using the embedded server managed by Spring Boot rather than trying to use the server's own settings.

Comment: ye, got that now, too.